# R data Import from a structured file

Tags: r, import

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
year 1: ...
year 2: ...
....
....
[data]
1,2,3,4
3,4,5
3,5,6,7,8,9
...
```

so basically it will have `n` lines before the `[data]` line,
and what's below the data line is what I want to read in.

I know I can delete the headers manually but it'd be ideal if I could have R detect the keyword `[data]` and read in what's after that.

Any suggestions?

Also, as you can see, I have different numbers of variables on each line for the actual data .
Is there any way to read it such that the line separation is preserved?

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing it:

```
csvAfter <- function(file, marker="[data]", blank.lines.skip=FALSE) {
  lines <- readLines(file)
  i <- match(marker, lines)
  if (is.na(i)) {
    warning("Didn\'t find ", marker)
    return(NULL)
  }
  f <- textConnection(paste(lines[-(1:i)], collapse="\n"))
  on.exit(close(f), add=TRUE)
  return(read.csv(f, header=FALSE, fill=TRUE,
                  blank.lines.skip=blank.lines.skip))
}
```

Example:

```
r <- "year 1: ...
year 2: ...
....
....
[data]
1,2,3,4
3,4,5
3,5,6,7,8,9"
print(csvAfter(textConnection(r)))
```

Comment: what if some lines are blank and I'd like to read it in as NAs?

Comment: That corresponds to blank.lines.skip=FALSE for read.csv. I've modified the code above to handle that case as you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is great for automatically detecting the flag "[data]", which will make it adaptable for input files with different numbers of lines before the data.

If you just need to do this one time you can include "skip = " in the call to read.csv or read.table

eg, read.table(file, skip = n)